# Does anyone make a 3 circuit switch?

Tags: electrical, switch

I would like to run 3 separate 120 volt items 10.2 max amp per item using 3 separate circuits, but only have a single switch box to use. I have seen single circuit in 3 switch out, but want 3 in 3 out. Does anyone make this?

Comment: With a quick search, I haven't found any yet. I have found an interesting [2 in, 3 out](https://www.legrand.us/radiant/products/switches/rcd113w.aspx) It has 2 switches on top which use one common hot and a 3rd switch on the bottom which uses another hot (and which can also be a 3-way switch). But I haven't yet found a true 3/3, which you need to get 10A per switch.

Comment: You might be able to use a single switch to control three relays.

Comment: Feels like that might be too many wires for the box...  that's a total of 6 14/3 cables coming into one single switch box?  Maybe I misunderstand what you're asking tho...

Comment: @JPhi1618 6 14/2.

Comment: If they're all switch loops, you could get away with 3 14/3s, but I also didn't find any when searching.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Pass & Seymour *Despard* should git-r-dun.

You have a much bigger problem though. *That's an awful lot of wires*.

Assuming you have 3 supply cables and 3 onward cables, all /2, that means **12** conductors.   +2 for the yoke, +1 for all grounds, and +1 for all cable clamps, totals **16** conductor units.

With #14 wire that will be 32 cubic inches.   With #12 wire that will be 36 cubic inches.

A single box is about 10-12ci, so that ain't gonna happen.   A 4x4 2-gang box is 22 ci, and normal drywall 1-gang mud rings don't add enough cubes to save you.  They do make 10.2 ci. mud rings, but those won't work with drywall.

You are better off going to a 4-11/16" square box which 42 cubic inches depending on depth.  That with a 1-gang mud ring will suffice.

Now if you use all *switch loops*, you have 9 conductors, so with yoke+ground+clamps that is  13 wire counts. with the yoke+ground+clamps.  That's 26 c.i. For #14 wire and 29.25 c.i. with #12.  That *might* *barely* scootch under with a 4x4 box and a 1-gang mud ring if #14.